# Is it possible to import an existing svn repository into Google Code?

Tags: svn, google-code

I have a private project I've been tinkering with for a while. I'm thinking of putting it up on Google Code in case anyone else finds it interesting.

**Is it possible for me to import my existing svn repository into Google Code, or will I have to create a new one and lose my change history?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How do I import an existing Subversion repository?](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_an_existing_Subversion_repository?)